# Is bluetoothapis.h header compatibale in uwp

Tags: visual-c++, uwp

I was trying to create an app that connects via bluetooth using some existing code from MFC platform.

In the existing code files they used

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2bth.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <atlstr.h>
#include <CString>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <thread>
#include <map>
#include <rpc.h>
#include <bluetoothapis.h>
```

These headers.
But when I take out the of file codes and use in a separate Universal windows DLL type project it gives errors like below.

```
Error   C2065   'AUTHENTICATION_REQUIREMENTS': undeclared identifier    
Error   C3861   'BluetoothAuthenticateDeviceEx': identifier not found
Error   C2065   'BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS_STRUCT': undeclared identifier   
Error   C2065   'BLUETOOTH_AUTHENTICATE_RESPONSE': undeclared identifier    
Error   C2065   'BLUETOOTH_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD_NUMERIC_COMPARISON'    
Error   C2065   'BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO': undeclared identifier  
Error   C2065   'BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO': undeclared identifier  
Error   C2065   'BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO_STRUCT': undeclared identifier
Error   C2065   'BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS': undeclared identifier 
Error   C2065   'BTHPROTO_RFCOMM': undeclared identifier    
Error   C2065   'BT_PORT_ANY': undeclared identifier
```

even though when include the <bluetoothapis.h> header it does not say error. The references are traversable (BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO, BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO_STRUCT etc.) by ctrl+left_mouse click in Visual Studio. But the code is not compiling.

I can not quite get the reason why.
any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could press **F12** over `bluetoothapis.h` to view the document, and you will see there is a **#if** statement `#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP)` at the beginning which says the header file is usable for **Desktop Win32 apps**(but not store apps). Universal Windows DLL project is not a Win32 app, therefore, `bluetoothapis.h` header could not be used in the project.

Comment: If your problem is resolved, it is better if you could mark the answer so that poeple with the same problems could find a solution quickly.